# C# WPF Smooth scrolling for cefsharp

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, cefsharp, smooth-scrolling

I'm using Cefsharp v79 (latest version) in my WPF application and I need to have smooth scroll for cefsharp pages
This is how my code looks like:

```
<Grid>
cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

But it did not work,
Any solutions ?

Comment: Are you trying to disable scrolling or are you have issues with the performance you are seeing?  There's no scroll viewer used internally,  so changing those values will have no effect.

Comment: I have issues with the performance of cefsharp (scrolling is not smooth)
And yeah, seems like it does not have any effect...
What should I do ?

Comment: Try adding the disable-threaded-scrolling command line args.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It worked!

This is how I get it to work:

```            CefSettings s = new CefSettings();
            s.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-threaded-scrolling", "1");
            Cef.Initialize(s);```

Do you suggest anything else for smooth scrolling etc?

Comment: Best not to post code as comments, you can post an answer to this question. The next release should bring performance improvements, it'll be available in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted @EternalC0der's comment into an answer so it's easier to read and implement.

The following code passes `disable-threaded-scrolling` argument to the browser:

```
CefSettings s = new CefSettings(); 
s.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-threaded-scrolling", "1"); 
Cef.Initialize(s);
```